# Retrofit - invalid parameters in call

Tags: java, api, retrofit

I've just get the code from response, and it says, that my request parameters are wrong, what should my api call look like then?

Here's the hardcoded api call from documenatation

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=[API_KEY]&with_genres=27
```

Here's my api call

```
@GET("3/search/movie")
Call<itemList_model> test(@Query("api_key") String key,@Query("with_genres") int query);
```

Code

```
    Invalid parameters: Your request parameters are incorrect.
```

Retrofit call

```
public void getListViewItems() {
    String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/";
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    apiCall api = retrofit.create(apiCall.class);
    Call<itemList_model> call = api.test("API_KEY",27); <- 27 stand's for horror genres.
    call.enqueue(new Callback<itemList_model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<itemList_model> call, Response<itemList_model> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.code());
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.code());
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<itemList_model> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The last sentence is a runtime exception or response body from the remote API? Please show how you invoke `lookForMovieByGivenValue(...)`

Comment: It's response from the body. I'll put the retrofit call in the question

Comment: Can I have any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo. Should be:

> https://api.themoviedb.org/3/**discover**/movie?api_key=[API_KEY]&with_genres=27

But:

> https://api.themoviedb.org/3/**search**/movie?api_key=[API_KEY]&with_genres=27

Working code

```
package test;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface RetrofitProxy {

    @GET("3/discover/movie")
    Call<Object> test(@Query("api_key") String apiKey, @Query("with_genres") int genreCode);
}
```

```
package test;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RetrofitTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/";

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitProxy retrofitProxy = retrofit.create(RetrofitProxy.class);
        Call<Object> call = retrofitProxy.test("API_KEY", 27);

        Response<Object> execute = call.execute();
        System.out.println(execute.raw());
        System.out.println(execute.isSuccessful());
        System.out.println(execute.body());
    }
}
```